# Systemd service stopped suddenly

Tags: server, python, services, postgresql, flask

We have a flask python application that runs normally on terminal without error. We converted it to systemd service(ubuntu), but the problem is that the service runs normally then stopped suddenly without any error.
Os used is ubuntu desktop 18.04

This is a sample of what happened:

```
ubuntu-MS-7A72 python[10026]: insert done
ubuntu-MS-7A72 python[10026]: insert done
ubuntu-MS-7A72 python[10026]: insert done
ubuntu-MS-7A72 python[10026]: insert done
ubuntu-MS-7A72 python[10026]: insert done
ubuntu-MS-7A72 python[10026]: insert done
ubuntu-MS-7A72 python[10026]: insert done
ubuntu-MS-7A72 systemd[1]: detection_tracking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
ubuntu-MS-7A72 systemd[1]: detection_tracking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
ubuntu-MS-7A72 systemd[1]: detection_tracking.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
ubuntu-MS-7A72 systemd[1]: detection_tracking.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
ubuntu-MS-7A72 systemd[1]: Stopped detection service.
ubuntu-MS-7A72 systemd[1]: Started detection service.
ubuntu-MS-7A72 systemd[1]: Stopping detection service...
ubuntu-MS-7A72 systemd[1]: Stopped detection service.
ubuntu-MS-7A72 systemd[1]: Started detection service.
```

Comment: It's a python exit code.  Add more log output to your python application.  What user is the process running on in systemd?  Can you post your systemd service file you created?

Comment: [Unit]
Description= detection service
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=ubuntu
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/Documents/
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/python /home/ubuntu/Documents/test.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Comment: the code is a python flask is executed normally on the terminal and keep running but when I converted it into a service it works for a time then it stops suddenly without error

Comment: Do you plan on running it with uWSGI?  Without additional logging I can't be certain what the issue is.  You could use a shell script to call your python instead and capture the output from python.  I suspect the problem is that you are using a custom python path and it's not picking up the packages for it.

Comment: My code is a flask that contains a function that execute a bash file my aim is that my flask code keep running all time like a service i dont have an idea about uWSGI

Comment: The bash file activate another environment using anaconda

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit]